# Creating a project in lumen

Tags: php, lumen

I came across two different commands creating a project in lumen:

> composer create-project --prefer-dist laravel/lumen myProject

and the other one is:

> lumen new myProject

I've always used the second one. Are there any advantages in using the first one, despite it being slow to run?

Comment: They do essentially the same thing - `lumen new` just downloads it from `http://cabinet.laravel.com/latest_lumen.zip`. That said, `composer` may fetch more up-to-date versions of some dependencies if they've had releases since the last time `latest_lumen.zip` was generated.